# Using ember-cli-selectize multiselect on query params

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, selectize.js, ember-query-params

I'm currently using [ember-cli-selectize](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-cli-selectize) on a query param in ember.js. Pretty much like the following:

**Template**

```
{{ember-selectize
  content=makes
  optionValuePath="content.make"
  optionLabelPath="content.make"
  value=car_makes
  selection=carMakes
  multiple=false
  placeholder="Filter by car make..." }}
```

**Controller**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   queryParams: ['car_makes'],
   car_makes: null,
   carMakes: Ember.A([])
});
```

However, I want to set 'multiple' to 'true' in my template and have an multiselect. Doing so in multiple mode means that 'value' is no longer supported.

The [author suggests](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-cli-selectize/pull/59) using a computed value, like so:

```
car_makes: Ember.computed.mapBy('carMakes', 'make')
```

The only problem is, [Ember does not support query params as a computed value](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/9819).

So, can anyone think of a way to trick Ember around this? Or am I going to have to make my own selectize component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `add-value` and `remove-value` actions provided by [ember-cli-selectize](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-cli-selectize). Take a look at the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/9f3883fc1155a7bc9cb43c212643843d?openFiles=templates.my-route.hbs%2C&route=%2Fmy-route). As you can see in `my-route.hbs`, I provided action handlers for `add-value` and `remove-value`. In `my-route.js` you can see how selected/deselected value iss added to/remove from `car_makes` which is an array; not a computed property. Hope this helps.

Comment: I made some improvements on your suggestion. The main thing was the selectize input was not populated upon a refresh of the page. Some other things were that I needed to use Ember.A on my version of Ember, and I also wanted to mess with the formatting of what was stored in the query param. [Here is my twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/30bbf117dc95d2e0d24891945f02092a?openFiles=routes.my-route.js%2C). I'm also unsure if I handled my route the correct way.

Comment: i will have a look at it when i have time.